# access(2) system call security issue

Tags: unix

access(2) man page says,

> CAVEAT
>        Access() is a potential security hole and should never be used.

But what is the security hole and why I should not use it?

Comment: Another question: If it's such a big security issue, why does it even exist? If it should never ever be used, then wouldn't it be better to just remove it immediately and let any program that _does_ use it break, because of the security vulnerability that would exist otherwise?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Linux Man pages clearly [describes](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/access.2.html) it

> **Warning**: Using **`access()`** to check if a user is authorized to, for example, open
>          a file before actually doing so using open(2) creates a security hole, because
>          **the user might exploit the short time interval between checking and opening
>          the file to manipulate it**.  For this reason, the use of this system call
>          should be avoided.

Also note. For security reason security exploits are not easily reachable to public.

Comment: see my answer for an example exploitable scenario.

Answer (score 5):

From my system's man pages:

> Warning: Using access() to check if a user is authorized to, for example, open a file before actually doing so using open(2) creates a security hole, because the user  might  exploit  the  short  time interval  between checking and opening the file to manipulate it.  For this reason, the use of this system call should be avoided.  (In the example just described, a safer alternative would be to temporarily switch the process's effective user ID to the real ID and then call open(2).)

So, the problem is that it creates a race condition can be exploited by the user to gain access to other files.

Imagine the following example scenario. I create a file `/tmp/file` that I am allowed to write. Then, your uid-0 program calls `access()` to check if I am allowed to open this file for writing, before providing me write access to it.

In the short space between the calls to `access()` and `open()`, I can remove `/tmp/file` and replace it by a symlink to `/etc/crontab`. I can now get the system to run any program I like, since the application will happily give me write access to `/etc/crontab`.

Comment: > the application will happily give me write access to `/etc/crontab`

How? Why will not `open` return `EACCES`?

Comment: > the application will happily give me write access to `/etc/crontab`

How? Why will not `open` return `EACCES`?

Answer (score 0):

Check out: http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/access.2.html

> Warning: Using access() to check if a user is authorized to, for
>   example, open
>          a file before actually doing so using open(2) creates a security hole, because
>          the user might exploit the short time interval between checking and opening
>          the file to manipulate it.  For this reason, the use of this system call
>          should be avoided.  (In the example just described, a safer alternative would
>          be to temporarily switch the process's effective user ID to the real ID and
>          then call open(2).)

See also:

http://www.csl.sri.com/~ddean/papers/usenix04.pdf

[What is wrong with access()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11525164/what-is-wrong-with-access)