# Checking file access permissions for specified user in C / *nix

Tags: c, linux, unix, file-permissions, freebsd

Here is my problem. I need to check read permissions for specific file and specific user from C code on FreeBSD. I've written a piece of code:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    int r_ok;

    if(setuid(1002)){
        printf("Cant's set uid\n");
        exit(1); 
    }

    r_ok = access("/tmp/dir", R_OK);
    printf("error: %d: %s\n", errno, strerror(errno));
    printf("%d\n", r_ok);
    return 0;
}
```

In general it works fine, but when I set permissions for /tmp/dir like this:

```
d---r-x---  2 root  fruit1  512 Sep 10 18:20 /tmp/dir
```

the program ouputs

```
error: 13: Permission denied
-1
```

althou user with UID 1002 is a valid member of group fruit1:

```
# groups 1002
orange fruit1
```

I will be greatfull for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setuid()` sets the real and effective user ID of the process, but does *not* modify the group access list, for that you have to call `setgid()`, `initgroups()` or `setgroups()`.

So your program runs with the used ID 1002 and with the original group ID and group
access list, and not with the group access list of the user 1002. 
That explains why the process does not have read permission to the directory.

Note that `access()` is considered a "security hole", (see for example [access() Security Hole](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7925177/access-security-hole)). 
It is generally better just to try to open a file or directory instead of checking
the read permissions beforehand.

Comment: Thank you so much. Your answer was wery helpful. I think I can use `faccessat` instead of `access` for same purposes.